# Sort, with your hands tied behind your back

Tags: code-golf, restricted-source, random, sorting

The problem is very simple: write a program that accepts a single unsigned integer from the command line, and prints out that many random numbers on the standard output, in ascending order.

For example:

input:

```
5
```

output <sup>(you can use any type of whitespace)</sup>:

```
557
9424
19212
32293
39135
```

However, you are not allowed to define any variables. **Any at all.**

Score is given by code length, shortest wins, and by up-votes if equal.

<sub>The random numbers can be anything generated by a reasonable pseudo-random generator with a uniform distribution: for example, integers at least 8 bits long (no cheap "0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 " one bit solutions, please), or real numbers (e.g. float) between 0 and 1.
In dynamically typed languages, the fist assignment counts as definition in our context, so no cheap Matlab solutions, please :)</sub>

Comment: Is it allowed to use library functions for generating the random numbers?

Comment: Yes, it is. Just be careful where you store the results.

Comment: I can hardly refrain from posting the 6 chars GolfScript solution: [`~[4]*p`](http://xkcd.com/221/).

Comment: Lots of languages require you to define variables to take an input. Are we allowed to use this variable?

Comment: *::doffs moderator hat::* To my mind this relies on a pointless distinction without a difference in which some bits of storage are dubbed "variables" and others are dubbed "not variables". You're fooling yourself if you think that anything interesting is happening here. See another equally silly example in http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2027/implement-a-sorting-algorithm-with-no-change .

Comment: @dmckee: Yes, I should have limited it to "C or derived languages". I remember some very nice IOCCC winners using extreme measures (like main calling itself recursively and overwriting itself, and other self-modifying programs) and I was expecting to see at least a few solutions such as those.

Comment: are we allowed to use predefined variables (variables built into the language itself)?

Comment: Do any languages have a fist assignment?

Comment: In Commodore Basic, it's impossible, because input HAS to be stored in a variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### J, 8 characters

If we can take the number of numbers to be generated at the end of the program like the Q solution, then:

```
/:~256?~
```

Example:

```
   /:~256?~8
18 21 91 201 212 226 246 253
```

If not, then taking input from the keyboard requires another 8 characters:

```
/:~256?~".1!:1[1
```

Answer (score 3):

## Q, 10

```
{asc x?1f}
```

.

```
q){asc x?1f}5
`s#0.08724017 0.1024432 0.2310108 0.2560658 0.8671096
```

Comment: Oh, I should have expected this. I should have placed a restriction so that such an easy language (for the problem) should not be allowed. Anyway, congratulations, I think you won! (I will wait a few days with accepting the answer, so that others can gather reputation too, with their painfully clever C++, Javascript and similar solutions)

Comment: Do implicitly defined variables count?!

Answer (score 2):

#### Perl - <strike>28 26</strike> 20 chars

<strike>`say sort map rand.$/,1..<>`</strike>

I realized the sorting isn't unnecessary, we only need random numbers in ascending order. `rand` will return a real in [0,1), so just add our iteration counter to each `rand` result.

```
say$_+rand for 1..<>
```

or

```
map{say$_+rand}1..<>
```

Answer (score 2):

### GolfScript, 14 chars

```
~{9.?rand}*]$`
```

Generating random numbers in GolfScript takes quite many characters, especially if you want to pick them from a reasonably large range.  Sorting the list takes only one char (`$`), though, and needs no variables.

Same code de-golfed and with comments added:

```
~            # eval input string, turning it into a number
{            # define a code block:
  9.? rand   #   push a random number between 0 and 99-1 onto the stack
} *          # execute the previous code block as many times as the input number indicates
]            # collect the random numbers off the stack into an array
$            # sort the array
`            # un-eval the array for output
```

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby, <s>42</s> 34

```
puts (1..gets.to_i).map{rand}.sort
```

This could probably be made smaller, but don't blame me - I don't even know Ruby. Also, that whitespace after `puts` is significant. Silly language ;)

Comment: I think you can get rid of the `.join` bit and use `p` instead of `puts` to save around 11 characters.

Comment: @Gareth: Thanks! I can't use both, though, because `p` prints it in a list representation.

Answer (score 1):

## Bash, 45 characters

```
eval `yes 'echo $RANDOM;'|head -n$1`|sort -n
```

Put in a file and run `sh file.sh 25` or replace `$1` by any number

Answer (score 1):

## Octave / MATLAB, 23

```
sort(rand(input(""),1))
```

Answer (score 1):

### C, 108 chars

You wanted a C (or derived) answer, so here's one.
Gets the number as the first parameter.
Works successfully with numbers up to 10 or so. With larger numbers, it usually overflows the stack (due to my awful algorithm).

```
f(x,m,r){x&&f(x-(r>m),r>m?printf("%d\n",r),r:m,rand());}
main(c,v)char**v;{srand(time(0));f(atoi(v[1]),0,0);}
```

Answer (score 1):

### R, 19/43(TRUE random) characters

```
sort(runif(scan()))
```

Just for fun, selecting TRUE random numbers:

```
library(random);sort(randomNumbers(scan()))
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Scala, 44:

```
(1 to readInt)map(util.Random.nextInt)sorted
```

Answer (score 0):

### Python, 73 characters

```
import sys,random
print sorted(eval("random.random(),"*int(sys.argv[1])))
```

Hopefully imports don't count as defining variables.

Comment: random and sys do count as variables unfortunately (<class: module>)

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell (102 / 71 chars)

As a proper program (102 chars)

```
import Random
import List
main=getLine>>=(\n->getStdGen>>=(print.sort.take n.randomRs(0,256*n))).read
```

Or in GHCi (71 chars)

```
:m Random List
getLine>>=(`fmap`getStdGen).(sort.).(.randoms).take.read
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 85 bytes

```
n=>{o=[];for(i=[];i.length<n;i.push(1))o.push(Math.random());return o.sort().join` `}
```

In JavaScript, [arrays are objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), not variables.

Answer (score 0):

### Java 8, 96 bytes

Because Java is obviously the right tool for this [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf)! <sup><sub>[/sarcasm]</sub></sup>

```java
n->java.util.stream.Stream.generate(Math::random).limit(n).sorted().forEach(System.out::println)
```

This is a `Consumer<Long>` or anything that can be implicitly cast to `long`. Prints random `double`s.

```java
n->                                 // Given an input n
   ...Stream.generate(Math::random) // Generate an infinite stream by calling Math.random()
   .limit(n)                        // Limit the stream to n elements
   .sorted()                        // On the sorted stream
   .forEach(System.out::println)    // Print each element on its own line
```