# Sorting a list of strings without using any built-in sort method

Tags: code-golf, sorting

The goal of this Code Golf is to create a program that sorts a list of strings (in ascending order), **without using any built-in sort method** (such as `Array.Sort()` in .NET, `sort()` in PHP, ...).  Note that this restriction excludes using a built-in method that sorts an array descending, and then reversing the array.

Some details:

- Your program should prompt for input, and this input is a list of strings containing only ASCII lower-case alphabetic characters `a-z`, comma-separated without spaces. For example:

  ```
  code,sorting,hello,golf
  ```
- The output should be the given list of strings, but sorted in ascending order, still comma-separated without spaces. For example:

  ```
  code,golf,hello,sorting
  ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## GolfScript, <s>26</s> 25 bytes

```
","/.,{{.2$<{\}*}*]}*","*
```

Straightfoward implementation of Bubble Sort.

Try it online in [Web GolfScript](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OyJjb2RlLHNvcnRpbmcsaGVsbG8sZ29sZiIgIyBTaW11bGF0ZSBpbnB1dCBmcm9tIFNURElOLgoKIiwiLy4se3suMiQ8e1x9Kn0qXX0qIiwiKiAgIyBTb3J0Lg%3D%3D).

#### How it works

```
","/     # Split the input string at commas.
.,       # Get the number of chunks.
{        # Do that many times:
  {      #   Reduce; for each element but the first:
    .2$< #     Push 1 if the last two strings are in descending order, 0 if not.
    {\}* #     Swap these strings that many times.
  }*]    #   Collect the strings dumped by reduce in an array.
}*       #
","*     # Join, separating by commas.
```

Comment: Nice! Accepting this one as answer because it's shorter than the currently accepted one.

Answer (score 10):

### Ruby <s>76</s> <s>54</s> 51 chars

```
x=gets.scan /\w+/;$><<x.dup.map{x.delete(x.min)}*?,
```

Comment: Very nice, [bogosort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort) :D

Comment: Wow, now it's even more interesting! I had to look at this for a while before I realized what was happening. I suppose now it's a slight variation of selection sort :P

Comment: Since the items are guaranteed to be alpha characters: `x=gets.scan /\w+/`

Answer (score 7):

## k (16 chars)

Probably doesn't really live up to the spirit of the problem. In k, there is no built in *sort* operator. `<x` returns a list of indices of items in x in sorted order.

```
{x@<x}[","\:0:0]
```

Comment: Well, this is a kind of built-in sorting, so unfortunately, I can't mark this as answer. I like the idea, however, so +1!

Answer (score 4):

### SED, 135

```
s/.*/,&,!,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/;:;s/\(,\([^,]*\)\(.\)[^,]*\)\(.*\)\(,\2\(.\)[^,]*\)\(.*!.*\6.*\3\)/\5\1\4\7/;t;s/^,\(.*\),!.*/\1/
```

Based on my [previous sorting entry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2035)

Answer (score 3):

### Ruby, 99 chars ([Gnome sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnome_sort))

```
a=gets.scan /\w+/
p=1
while a[p]
a[p]>a[p-1]?p+=2:(a[p],a[p-1]=a[p-1],a[p])
p-=1if p>1
end
$><<a*?,
```

This just barely beats my bubble sort implementation:

### Ruby, <s>110</s> <s>104</s> 101 chars ([Bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort))

```
s=gets.scan /\w+/
(z=s.size).times{(0..(z-2)).map{|i|s[i],s[i+1]=s[i+1],s[i]if s[i]>s[i+1]}}
$><<s*?,
```

This does `list.length` iterations, because worst-case scenario takes `list.length - 1` iterations and one more really doesn't matter, and saves 2 chars.

Just for fun, a Quicksort version:

### Ruby, 113 chars ([Quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort))

```
q=->a{if a[1]
p=a.shift
l=[]
g=[]
a.map{|x|(x>p ?g:l).push x}
q[l]+[p]+q[g]
else
a
end}
$><<q[gets.scan /\w+/]*?,
```

Comment: I found that this implementation of gnome sort loops infinitely when the input items are not all unique, e.g. a b b.

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, 141

```
import Data.List
m=minimum
s[]=[]
s l=m l:s(l\\[m l])
t[]=[]
t s=let(a,b)=span(/=',')s in a:t(drop 1 b)
main=interact$intercalate",".s.t.init
```

At least it’s… **sort** of efficient.

Comment: You can save 11 characters by using selection sort: `m=minimum` `s[]=[]` `s l=m l:(s$l\\[m l])` (replace your lines 2–4 with these lines).

Comment: The `init` doesn't seem to be necessary as there is neither a trailing `,`, nor a trailing newline. `t s=let(a,b)=span(/=',')s in a:t(drop 1 b)` can be shortened by using a pattern guard, using `(>',')` and dropping the space between `1 b`: `t s|(a,b)<-span(>',')s=a:t(drop 1b)`.

Comment: Using insertion with the insert function `x#(y:r)|y<x=y:x#r;x#r=x:r` is shorter. It can be used directly in `t` and as it does not use `(\\)` and `intercalate","` can be replaced by `tail.((',':)=<<)`, the import can be dropped. All together 101 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY1BCsMgEADvviKQQhRMoFdx@5GQwyaxidRq0D0o5O/WHuYyDMyJ6WOcqzX3vKgo7qIzFJX7yBqQVWQ0LzAvjLp0c5Sr0GO60PPXIAeRAHviewxX91wF@6L1YD2ZiBs9CK2bOG@dEqC1mKjWLexGphDJ@kOe7RzkEdxb/v0P "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

### vba, 165

```
Sub q()
c=","
s=InputBox("?")
Z=Split(s, c)
t=UBound(Z)
For i=1 To t-1
For j=i To t
If Z(i)>Z(j) Then a=Z(i):Z(i)=Z(j):Z(j)=a
Next
Next
Debug.Print Join(Z,c)
End Sub
```

Comment: I count 165 characters...

Comment: @Doorknob, fixed count... The greasemonkey script evidently gave me the wrong count as I was typing in the code.

Comment: You can get rid of a space in that `Split`.

Comment: Using `c=","` and calling `c` twice actually adds to the byte count in this case, contributing 7 bytes to the byte count, where as just using "," twice would contribute 6 bytes. You can lower your byte code by taking input directly from the sub call (`sub q(s)`) and assuming s is of type variant\string. You can lose one more byte by changing `For i=1 to` to `for i=1To`. you can lose 5 bytes by changing `Debug.Print Join...` to `Debug.?Join...`

Answer (score 2):

### PHP 83 bytes

```
<?for($x=fgetcsv(STDIN);$x;)${$x[0]>min($x)?x:a}[]=array_shift($x)?><?=join(~Ó,$a);
```

An *O(n<sup>3</sup>)* implementation of a selection sort. The `Ó` is character 211; a bit-inverted comma.

Sample usage:

```
$ more in.dat
code,sorting,hello,golf

$ php list-sort.php < in.dat
code,golf,hello,sorting
```

Answer (score 2):

## Scala, 122 bytes

### As a one-liner (88 bytes):

```
.permutations.filter(_.sliding(2).map(w=>w(0)<w.last).fold(true)((a,b)=>a&&b)).toSeq(0)
```

(it will sort a list by just doing `list.permutations.fil...` )

### As a program (122 bytes):

```
println(readLine.split(",").toSeq.permutations.filter(_.sliding(2).map(w=>w(0)<w.last).fold(true)((a,b)=>a&&b)).toSeq(0))
```

A longer version if you want it to read from stdin.

This iterate over all the permutations of the given list until it stumble on a sorted one. It's not fast as it takes about 12 seconds to sort a 10 elements list and well over a minute for a 11 elements one.

**[Edit]** items need to be unique or `<` can be replaced by `<=`.
Also, sorry for necro.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3 (80 chars)

```
l=input().split(',')
m=[]
while l:m+=[l.pop(l.index(min(l)))]
print(','.join(m))
```

Here is a variation of the while-statement that is of equal length:

```
while l:x=min(l);m+=[x];l.remove(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica <s>66</s> 56

```
Row[#[[Ordering@#]]&[InputString[]~StringSplit~","],","]
```

Some other solutions without the build-in symbol `Ordering`:

### Bogosort: <s>84</s> 74

```
NestWhile[RandomSample,InputString[]~StringSplit~",",!OrderedQ@#&]~Row~","
```

### Bubble Sort: <s>93</s> 83

```
Row[InputString[]~StringSplit~","//.{x___,i_,j_,y___}/;j~Order~i==1:>{x,j,i,y},","]
```

### Another solution as inefficient as bogosort: <s>82</s> 72

```
#~Row~","&/@Permutations[InputString[]~StringSplit~","]~Select~OrderedQ;
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3.5+, 73 bytes

This takes inspiration from [Steven Rumbalski's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/12841/31855) answer but uses list comprehension instead of a while loop; the number of iterations comes from the copied list `l` which is the reason this [requires additional unpacking generalizations and Python 3.5](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/)

```
l=input().split(',');print(*[l.pop(l.index(min(l)))for _ in[*l]],sep=',')
```

Answer (score 0):

### javascript 128

```
a=prompt().split(',');b=[];for(i in a){b.push(a[i]);k=0;for(j in b){j=k;b[j]>a[i]?[c=b[j],b.splice(j,1),b.push(c)]:k++}}alert(b)
```

[DEMO fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mendelthecoder/X78ud/5/).

i am looking for a way to eliminate `b`.

Comment: Remove the `[]` around the part after the `?` to save 2 chars

Comment: @Doorknob i have tried it before i get `SyntaxError: missing : in conditional expression` because `?:;` (the shorthand `if/else`) is only supposed to take two pecies of code to execute (i.e. `true?b++:b--;`) using `[`,`]` is a hack, im still not sure why it works, i think its understood as a empty array declaration, like placing a random string or number as a stand-alone command. but you can still feel free to upvote.

Comment: Hmm, I suppose  I was mistaken. The comma operator can execute multiple pieces of code at once. Using parenthesis works, so I suppose the `?:` operator's precedence is lower than `,`

Comment: No, did you try? Parenthesis still work...

Comment: @Doorknob [your right](http://jsfiddle.net/mendelthecoder/X78ud/9/), however i tried `{`,`}` and [it didnt work](http://jsfiddle.net/mendelthecoder/X78ud/11/) - i get `SyntaxError: missing : after property id`. as for precedence parentheses is always first. i still would like a upvote....

Comment: That's because `{}` is for object literals... yes, the whole point of parenthesis is to gain higher precedence.

Answer (score 0):

## R

#### Bubble Sort: <s>122</s> 118 characters

```
a=scan(,"",sep=",");h=T;while(h){h=F;for(i in 1:(length(a)-1)){j=i+1;if(a[i]>a[j]){a[j:i]=a[i:j];h=T}}};cat(a,sep=",")
```

#### Bogosort: 100 characters

```
a=scan(,"",sep=",");while(any(apply(embed(a,2),1,function(x)x[1]<x[2]))){a=sample(a)};cat(a,sep=",")
```

Answer (score 0):

### Perl, 159

```
perl -F"," -lape "$m=$m<length()?length():$m for@F;$_{10**(2*$m)*sprintf'0.'.'%02d'x$m,map-96+ord,split//}=$_ for@F;$_=join',',map$_{$_+0},grep exists$_{$_+0},'0'.1..'0'.10**100"
```

This never stood a chance to win, but decided to share it because I liked the logic even if it's a mess :) The idea behind it, is to convert each word into an integer (done using the [ord](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ord.html) function), we save the number as a key in a hash and the string as a value, and then we iterate increasingly through all integers (1..10**100 in this case) and that way we get our strings sorted.

**WARNING**: Don't run this code on your computer, since it loops through trillions+ of integers. If you want to test it, you can lower the upper range limit and input non-lengthy strings. If for any reason this is against the rules, please let me know and I'll delete the entry!

Answer (score 0):

### JS: 107 chars - Bubble Sort

```
a=prompt().split(/,/);for(i=a.length;i--;)for(j=0;j<i;)a[j]>a[j+1]?[b=a[j],a[j]=a[++j],a[j]=b]:j++;alert(a)
```

I looked at @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight's answer and tried to improve it, but ended up implementing it slightly differently.

Answer (score 0):

## Java, 134 bytes

A method that implements Gnome Sort.

```
void s(String[]a){int m=a.length-1,i=0;while(i<m){while(i>=0&&a[i].compareTo(a[i+1])>0){String t=a[i];a[i]=a[i+1];a[i+1]=t;i--;}i++;}}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Swift, 101 bytes

```
func s(a:[String])->[String]{return a.count<2 ? a:(s(a.filter{$0<a[0]})+[a[0]]+s(a.filter{$0>a[0]}))}
```

Ungolfed:

```
//quicksort
func sort(a:[String]) -> [String]
{
    //return the array if its length is less than or equal to 1
    if a.count <= 1
    {
        return a
    }
    //choose the first element as pivot
    let pivot = a[0]
    //retrieve all elements less than the pivot
    let left = a.filter{ $0 < pivot }
    //retrieve all elements greater than the pivot
    let right = a.filter{ $0 > pivot }
    //sort the left partition, append a new array containing the pivot,
    //append the sorted right partition
    return sort(left) + Array<String>(arrayLiteral: pivot) + sort(right)
}
```

Comment: This does not take and return the strings in the given comma-separated format.

Answer (score 0):

## , 24 chars / 30 bytes (noncompetitive)

```
ï⇔Ĕ⍪;↻ïꝈ)ΞÿѨŗ ï,⇀$≔МƵï;Ξ
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter3.html?eval=false&input=code%2Csorting%2Chello%2Cgolf&code=%C3%AF%E2%87%94%C4%94%E2%8D%AA%3B%E2%86%BB%C3%AF%EA%9D%88%29%CE%9E%C3%BF%D1%A8%C5%97%20%C3%AF%2C%E2%87%80%24%E2%89%94%D0%9C%C6%B5%C3%AF%3B%CE%9E)</kbd>

Using selection sort!

## Explanation

```
ï⇔Ĕ⍪;↻ïꝈ)ΞÿѨŗ ï,⇀$≔МƵï;Ξ // implicit: ï=input, Ξ=[]
ï⇔Ĕ⍪;                    // split ï along commas and set it to ï
     ↻ïꝈ)                // while ï's length > 0
         Ξÿ              // push to Ξ:
           Ѩŗ ï,⇀$≔МƵï;  // removed minimum item(s) from ï using builtin
                       Ξ // get sorted array
```

Basically recursively removes and pushes the minimum from the input to another array.

Answer (score 0):

## Ceylon (Bogosort), 119

```ceylon
String s(String i)=>",".join([*i.split(','.equals)].permutations.select((p)=>!any{for([x,y]in p.paired)y<x})[0]else[]);
```

[Try it online!](https://try.ceylon-lang.org/?gist=092d664fc0c65ac24505d8e88b5b852e)

I found the [`permutations`](https://modules.ceylon-lang.org/repo/1/ceylon/language/1.3.3/module-doc/api/Collection.type.html#permutations) method and thus ended up with Bogosort (a non-random variant).

Formatted and commented:

```ceylon
// a function `s` mapping a String `i` to a String
String s(String i) =>
    // the end result is created by joining the iterable in (...).
    ",".join(
        // take the input, split it on commas, make the result a sequence.
        [*
            i.split(','.equals)   // → {String+}
           ]                      // → [String+]
        // get the iterable of all permutations of this sequence.
        // Yes, this is an iterable of O(n!) sequences (though likely
        // lazily computed, we don't need all in memory at once).
        .permutations              // → {[String+]*}
        // filter this iterable for ordered sequences.
        // Using select instead of filter makes this
        // eager instead of lazy, so we are actually iterating
        // through all n! sequences, and storing the ordered
        // ones. (All of those are equal.)
        .select(
            // this is our function to check whether this sequence
            // is ordered in ascending order.
            (p)=>
               // return if none of the following iterable of booleans is true.
                !any {
                   // This is a for-comprehension. Inside an named argument list
                   // (what we have here, although there is no name) for a
                   // function which wants an iterable, this becomes an iterable,
                   // lazily built from the existing iterable p.paired,
                   // which is just an iterable with all pairs of subsequent
                   // elements.
                      for([x,y] in p.paired)
                        // for each such pair, we evaluate this expression, which
                        // is true when the sequence is not ordered correctly.
                           y < x         // → Boolean
                        // → {Boolean*}
                    }  //   → Boolean
                 //  → Boolean([String+])
               ) // → [[String+]*]
         // we now have a sequence of (correctly sorted) sequences.
         // just take the first one.
         // If we had used `.filter` before, this would have to be `.first`.
               [0]    // → [String+]|Null
         // in case this is null, which can only happen if the original array was
         // empty, so there were no permutations, just use the empty sequence
         //  again. (Actually, split never returns an empty array, so this can't
         //  happen, but the type checker can't know that.)
               else []    // → [String*]
    // so that is what we pass to the join method.
        )   // → String
    ;
```

Without the formatting and parsing it becomes just 90 bytes:

```ceylon
String[]s(String[]i)=>i.permutations.select((p)=>!any{for([x,y]in p.paired)y<x})[0]else[];
```

[Try it online!](https://try.ceylon-lang.org/?gist=8a291b336c386b279837ea9151ac4762)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 77 bytes

```perl
map{$F[$_]gt$F[$_+1]&&(@F[$_,$_+1]=@F[$_+1,$_])for 0..@F-2}@F;$_=join',',"@F"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z83saBaxS1aJT42vQRMaxvGqqlpOICYOmCerQNEGMiL1UzLL1Iw0NNzcNM1qnVws1aJt83Kz8xT11HXUXJwU/r/P1knSSfxX35BSWZ@XvF/XV9TPQNDg/@6BW76OvoA)

Simple bubble sort.

Answer (score 0):

## `ruby -plaF,` , 70 bytes

```
o=[]
$F.map{|s|i=o;s.bytes{|b|i=i[b]=[*i[b]]};i[0]=s<<?,}
$_=o*''
chop
```

O(n), if you pretend that resizing and compacting an array is free (it is very not free).

We create a deeply and unevenly nested array `o` by putting a string with bytes b<sub>1</sub>,b<sub>2</sub>...b<sub>n</sub> into the array at position o[b<sub>1</sub>][b<sub>2</sub>]...[b<sub>n</sub>]. The result looks like `[,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,["a,",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, [,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, ["abc,"], ["abd,"], ["abe,"]], ["ac,"], ["ad,"]],, ["c,"]]`

Then we flatten and output it.

Answer (score 0):

> Reusing [my own answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/108550/29325) on [Sort an Integer List](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77836/sort-an-integer-list)

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 211 bytes

```
set L [split [gets stdin] ,]
set i 0
time {incr j;set x 0;while \$x<$i {if \"[lindex $L $i]"<"[lindex $L $x]" {set L [lreplace [linsert $L $x [lindex $L $i]] $j $j]};incr x};incr i} [llength $L]
puts [join $L ,]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7BCoMwEETvfsUgOebQu/0E/8DmUHSrK9tEzJYGxG9PY@ulsLAw83ZntJecIyladHERVnQjaUTUgb2DddVhMi6V8pOwse9XzM0hJlya98RCuJl0NVzMB251J@wHSjAtDLv6@ickV2M742SlRe494QAirfoj8P/Awcxl3N58o9O5eS@ckB91KqCrllcp3c2B/XFnXc59GMjGsCr70U4kEuwY5PEB)